Receipt for writing down the Boltzmann-equation for a given interaction
Suppose one has a gas consisting of two particles, which are known to primarily interact with each other through a specific interaction. To describe the behavior of the particle densities, I would like to write down the Boltzmann equation. On the one hand, I could of course do this with the collision integral, but I already know that the right side of the equation can also be written using the thermally averaged cross-section and the difference between the powers of the particle density and the equilibrium particle density. How do I find out this difference? Is there a simple method for this? For the interaction $a+a\to b+b$, I know that it is simply the difference $(n_a^2-n_{a,eq}^2)$. But how would this look for an arbitrary interaction? The derivations I find mostly limit themselves to this interaction and that doesn't really help me further. If the question is too specific: Do you have a good recommendation where I can find an answer to this?

I don't think boltzmann equation can be obtained for 2 particle system . But I may be wrong
